# is there a way to self reference within a list generation in python

Tags: python, list

I want to create the following list of tuples of strings:

```
pairs = [(s1,s2) for s1 in S for s2 in S if s1 != s2 and (s2,s1) not in self]
```

Obviously `not in self` doesn't work. Is there a way to achieve this with a generator expression?
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This seems like an XY problem. If you just want to get those pairs, there are better ways to do it. Self-reference of the sort you describe doesn't work. A generator expression can sort of help, by making things lazily evaluated so that you don't have temporary copies, but you still need to do the filtering at an outer layer. The canonical way to remove duplicates from a sequence (generator expressions qualify) is by creating a `set` from it. A set comprehension lets you do that filtering directly. If you need to maintain order, then it's more difficult and slower.

Comment: In short, this is a common question either way, but it depends on *what you actually want*.

Comment: There is no generator here, btw

Answer (score 0):

You don't want a list, you want a set:

```
pairs = {(s1,s2) for s1 in S for s2 in S if s1 != s2}
```

Sets can only have a single element of a given (hashable) value. Your self-referential filter clause (`not in self`) is essentially asking to ensure that there is only one such element, which is what a set is for. You can easily `list(pairs)` after this if you need a list instead of a set for what you're doing.

A downside of this is that the values must be hashable (immutable values, or mutable values that can be hashed).

Comment: This presumes a) that the goal is to learn a deduplication technique and b) that order of output doesn't matter. There are several possible other interpretations of the question. It could be that order matters. It could be that the goal is to create those pair values by any technique, in which case it's completely an XY problem and `itertools.combinations` is correct. It could be that OP wants to learn general technique for self-reference in comprehensions and/or generator expressions, and just has an unfortunately chosen example.

Comment: If the intended interpretation *is* this one, then the question is a common duplicate anyway. In fact, it is in every case except the general technique interpretation, in which case I'm pretty sure the answer is a simple "no, it is not possible in a single pass; filter the data afterward". Depending on how general "general" is - maybe there is some walrus operator hack.

Comment: This is all true - though I think there is an 80% chance this handles what they are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Karl is correct it is intended as an XY problem where order matters. Therefore your approach does not work. I just wanted to know if this can be achieved with a one liner.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no way to reference the object being constructed by a comprehension.

Do it in two steps: First create the list, then add to the list in a loop.

```
pairs = []
for s1 in S:
    for s2 in S:
        if (s1, s2) not in pairs:
            pairs.append((s1, s2))
```